# Can I safely remove /usr/bin/java from Mountain Lion 10.8.2?

Tags: macos, security, java

If I do so, will something, such as a service, break?

Comment: It's safe provided you also remove any plist in Application Support and Preferences folders that reference /usr/bin/java.

Comment: Why would you need/want to remove it?

Answer (score 3):

Mac App Store apps and OS X core applications and services don't depend on Java, but some 3rd party applications (like LibreOffice) do, and they will break if you delete `/usr/bin/java`.

Since `/usr/bin/java` is a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link):

```
/usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

if you notice that an application complains about missing Java or fails to start after deleting `/usr/bin/java` simply recreate it like this:

1. Open Applications>Utilities>Terminal
2. Make the symlink (type your password if asked):

   ```
   $ sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java /usr/bin/java
   ```

Comment: However removing just /usr/bin/java will not add to any form of security as many apps use the /System/.../java path

Comment: It is still unclear why the OP wants to remove `/usr/bin/java`, but if it is security related and many apps use the `/System/Library/...` path as you say (could you provide some more information about that? is it an Apple recommendation?), then no, it won't increase security much.

Comment: FWIW it is not a symlink on 12.6